# Print the body of the modal using dompdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-5, dompdf

The generate-classroll-pdf.php page states Modal content is not provided when I click the print button. I can't get the modal body to show up in dompdf.

This is the classroll.php.

```
<?php
include_once("../includes/connection.php");
include_once("../includes/dataValues.php");
require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';


$con = connection();



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

    <title>Classroll - MNHS</title>
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Nunito:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
    <link href="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/vendor/quill/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/vendor/quill/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/vendor/simple-datatables/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
    <link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            /* Remove border spacing */
            width: 100%;
        }

        .table th,
        .table td {
            border: none;
            /* Remove cell borders */
            padding: 8px;
            /* Add padding for cell content */
            text-align: ;
            /* Center-align cell content */
        }

        .table th {
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
            /* Add a background color for header cells */
        }

        .bold-uppercase-row {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            /* Convert the text to uppercase */
            font-weight: ;
            /* Make text bold */
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <?php include 'html/header.php'; ?>
    <?php include 'html/sidebar.php'; ?>

    <main id="main" class="main">

        <div class="pagetitle">
            <h1>Classroll</h1>
            <!--<nav class="d-flex justify-content-end">Statistics</nav>-->
            <nav class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="dashboard.php">Class</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Classroll</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <section class="section">
            <div class="row justify-content-center"> <!-- Center the content horizontally -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="card w-100"> <!-- Apply w-100 class to the card to ensure full width -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">List of Sections</h5>

                            <!-- Centered and Responsive Table with 100% width -->
                            <div class="table-responsive"> <!-- Make the table responsive -->
                                <table class="table w-100"> <!-- Apply w-100 class to ensure full width -->
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">View Classroll</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Section</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Grade Level</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Adviser</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Academic Program</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <?php
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sections
                            INNER JOIN gradelevel ON gradelevel.gradeID = sections.gradeID
                            INNER JOIN academic_programs ON academic_programs.academicID = sections.academicID
                            INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.teacherID = sections.teacherID";

                                    $sec = $conn->query($sql); // Execute the query using the database connection
                                    if ($sec && $sec->num_rows > 0) { // Check if the query executed successfully
                                        while ($row = $sec->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            //var_dump($row); // Add this line
                                    
                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary view-button"
                                                        data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
                                                        data-section-id="<?php echo $row['sectionID']; ?>">View</button>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['sectionName']; ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['gradeLevel']; ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['tfname']; ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?php echo $row['acadName']; ?>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5">No sections found</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Centered and Responsive Table with 100% width -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Classroll list</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p><strong>Section:</strong> <span id="modalSectionName"></span></p>
                        <p><strong>Grade Level:</strong> <span id="modalGradeLevel"></span></p>
                        <p><strong>Adviser:</strong> <span id="modalAdviser"></span></p>
                        <p><strong>Academic Program:</strong> <span id="modalAcademicProgram"></span></p>

                        <!-- Table to display students -->
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>LRN</th>
                                    <th>Student Name</th>
                                    <th>Gender</th>
                                    <th>Remarks</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="studentTableBody">
                                <!-- Student data will be populated here using JavaScript -->
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="4">
                                                Total: <span id="totalStudentsCount">0</span>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" id="printPdfButton">Print</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main><!-- End #main -->

    <!-- ======= Footer ======= 
  <footer id="footer" class="footer">
    <div class="copyright">
      &copy; Copyright <strong><span>NiceAdmin</span></strong>. All Rights Reserved
    </div>
    <div class="credits">
      <!-- All the links in the footer should remain intact. -->
    <!-- You can delete the links only if you purchased the pro version. -->
    <!-- Licensing information: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/ -->
    <!-- Purchase the pro version with working PHP/AJAX contact form: https://bootstrapmade.com/nice-admin-bootstrap-admin-html-template/ -->
    <!-- Designed by <a href="https://bootstrapmade.com/">BootstrapMade</a>
    </div>
  </footer><!-- End Footer -->

    <a href="#" class="back-to-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i
            class="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>

    <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
    <script src="../assets/vendor/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/vendor/chart.js/chart.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/vendor/echarts/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/vendor/quill/quill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/vendor/simple-datatables/simple-datatables.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>

    <!-- Template Main JS File -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>



    <script>
        // Function to handle the "View" button click
        $(".view-button").click(function () {
            var sectionId = $(this).data("section-id"); // Get the section ID from the button's data attribute

            // Send an AJAX request to fetch the section details and student data
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_section_details.php', // Replace with the actual PHP file that fetches section details and students
                type: 'POST',
                data: { sectionId: sectionId },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Populate the modal with the retrieved data
                    $('#modalSectionName').text(data.sectionName);
                    $('#modalGradeLevel').text(data.gradeLevel);
                    $('#modalAdviser').text(data.adviserName);
                    $('#modalAcademicProgram').text(data.academicProgramName);

                    // Populate the student table
                    var studentTableBody = $('#studentTableBody');
                    studentTableBody.empty(); // Clear any previous data

                    if (data.students && data.students.length > 0) {
                        // Initialize the student number
                        var studentNumber = 1;

                        // Loop through the student data and add rows to the table
                        data.students.forEach(function (student) {
                            var row = '<tr class="bold-uppercase-row">' +
                                '<td>' + studentNumber + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + student.lrn + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + student.lname + ', ' + student.fname + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + student.gender + '</td>' +
                                '<td>Enrolled</td>' +
                                '</tr>';
                            studentTableBody.append(row);

                            // Increment the student number for the next student
                            studentNumber++;
                        });

                        // Update the total student count
                        $('#totalStudentsCount').text(data.students.length);
                    } else {
                        // If no students found, display a message
                        studentTableBody.html('<tr><td colspan="5">No students found</td></tr>');

                        // Update the total student count to 0
                        $('#totalStudentsCount').text('0');
                    }

                    // Show the modal
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error fetching section details');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
      $("#printPdfButton").click(function () {
    // Get the modal content using jQuery
    var modalContent = $("#exampleModal").html();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'generate-classroll-pdf.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { modalContent: modalContent },
        success: function () {
            // PDF generated successfully
        },
        error: function () {
            // Handle errors
        }
    });
});
    </script>

</body>



</html>
```

Here is the get_selection_details.php

```
<?php
include_once("../includes/connection.php");

$con = connection();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['sectionId'])) {
        $sectionId = $_POST['sectionId'];
        
        // Fetch section details from the database based on sectionId
        $sqlSection = "SELECT sections.sectionName, gradelevel.gradeLevel, teachers.tfname, academic_programs.acadName
                       FROM sections
                       INNER JOIN gradelevel ON gradelevel.gradeID = sections.gradeID
                       INNER JOIN academic_programs ON academic_programs.academicID = sections.academicID
                       INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.teacherID = sections.teacherID
                       WHERE sections.sectionID = $sectionId";
        
        $resultSection = $con->query($sqlSection);
        
        if ($resultSection && $resultSection->num_rows > 0) {
            $rowSection = $resultSection->fetch_assoc();
            
            // Fetch students belonging to the section
            $sqlStudents = "SELECT student.fname, student.lname, student.lrn, gender.gender FROM student 
            INNER JOIN gender ON gender.genderID = student.genderID
            WHERE sectionID = $sectionId";
            $resultStudents = $con->query($sqlStudents);
            
            $students = array();
            if ($resultStudents && $resultStudents->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($rowStudent = $resultStudents->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $students[] = $rowStudent;
                }
            }
            
            // Prepare JSON response
            $response = array(
                'sectionName' => $rowSection['sectionName'],
                'gradeLevel' => $rowSection['gradeLevel'],
                'adviserName' => $rowSection['tfname'],
                'academicProgramName' => $rowSection['acadName'],
                'students' => $students
            );
            
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Section not found'));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Invalid request'));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Invalid request method'));
}
?>
```

Here is the generate-classroll-pdf.php

```
<?php
require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

if (isset($_POST['modalContent'])) {
    $modalContent = $_POST['modalContent'];

    // Create Dompdf instance with options
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    // Load the HTML content
    $dompdf->loadHtml($modalContent);

    // Set paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

    // Render the PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // Output the PDF to the browser
    $dompdf->stream('classroll.pdf', ['Attachment' => false]);
} else {
    echo "Modal content not provided.";
}
?>
```

I want to be able to print the whole modal body from dompdf when I click the print button.[This is the Modal that I want to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YrG1.png)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)